# A small adjustment to the Multi-Armed Bandit problem

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

What class of problems does this belong to:

Similar to [multi-armed bandit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit), but with a small adjustment/difference: by choosing an action at every time step you not only receive the reward of that particular action, but also realize what the reward *would* have been if another action was taken.

Has this problem been studied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book [Introduction to Multi-Armed Bandits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.07272.pdf) by Aleksandrs Slivkins, the author distinguishes between 3 types of feedback that could be received by a bandit algorithm:

> *bandit feedback*, when the algorithm observes the reward for
> the chosen arm, and no other feedback; *full feedback*, when **the algorithm observes the rewards for all arms
> that could have been chosen**; and *partial feedback*, when some information is revealed, in addition to the
> reward of the chosen arm, but it does not always amount to full feedback.

Here are some examples from the book for each case:
[image]

So, what you are asking about may fall either under the partial or the full feedback cases.

Comment: and what algorithm would be able to deal with partial feedback?